# Запись ключа и значения из строки через регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, поиск, словари

Есть длинная строка со связанными значениями Штат-столица, формата:

> Айдахо (Центр Бойсе).Айова (Основной центр Де-Мойн).Алабама (Монтгомери).Аляска (Центр Джуно).

И необходимо пары штат-столица запихнуть в словарь

Я пытался сделать так:

Через регулярные выражения получаю отдельно штаты и города:

```
states = re.compile('''(
 (?!=[(])
 [А-Яа-я\s]+)
 ''', re.VERBOSE)
cities = re.compile('''(
(?<=[(])
[А-Яа-я\s]+)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

И хотел результаты этих поисков запихнуть в ключ-значение, но не смог додуматься как.

Знаю, что через for можно работать с разными частями регулярного выражений, типа:

```
for groups in phoneregex.findall(text):
```

Где groups мог быть как отдельной скобкой, так и словом, и можно было бы это запихать в:

```
StateCities = {}
StateCities.update(groups[1],groups[2])
```

Но это будет работать, только в том случае, если и штаты и города будут искаться только в одном поиске. А как это сделать я себе этого тоже не представляю.

И, скорее всего неправильно себе представляю принцип работы регулярных выражений.

Подскажите пожалуйста как грамотно через регулярные выражения вывести пары ключа-значения из строки и запихнуть их в словарь?

Чтобы в итоге получить один словарь, типа:
{'Айдахо': 'Центр Бойсе', 'Айова'': 'Основной центр Де-Мойн'...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `re.findall` с регулярным выражением с захватывающими подмасками:

```py
import re
s = 'Айдахо (Центр Бойсе).Айова (Основной центр Де-Мойн).Алабама (Монтгомери).Аляска (Центр Джуно).'
rx = re.compile(r'([^\W\d_]+(?:\s+[^\W\d_]+)*)\s*\(([^()]*)\)')
print( dict(re.findall(rx, s)) )
# => {'Айдахо': 'Центр Бойсе', 'Айова': 'Основной центр Де-Мойн', 'Алабама': 'Монтгомери', 'Аляска': 'Центр Джуно'}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/BWTEdD) и [регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/t60GRK/2).

`[^\W\d_]` находит любую букву Юникода. `re.findall(...)` возвращает кортежи со значениями, захваченными подмасками №1 и №2, они же используются для создания объекта типа dictionary.

**Подробности**

- `([^\W\d_]+(?:\s+[^\W\d_]+)*)` - Подсмаска №1: 1+ букв, за которыми следует 0 и более повторов 1+ пробельных символов и 1+ букв
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Подмаска №2: 0 и более символов, отличных от `(` и `)`
- `\)` - символ `)`

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но мне нужно, чтобы в качестве ключа была не подмаска, а штат, и не списком словарей, а словарь, типа: {'Айдахо': 'Центр Бойсе', 'Айова'': 'Основной центр Де-Мойн'...} Про подмаски незнал, как и про метод groupdict, буду изучать, но вот как в словарь сразу запихнуть искомые и ключ, и значение я ума не приложу :)

Comment: @vlad В следующий раз добавьте в вопрос пример ожидаемого результата.

Comment: Учту, спасибо, кажется, я уже понял как можно сделать. Эти же 2 группы можно просто в dict.update вставить

Comment: @vlad Да я же ответ изменил, смотрите, сравнивайте.

Comment: Спасибо! Что мой, что ваш метод работают. Только вот, если я даю на создание словаря из вашего решения, точно такое же регулярное выражение, но с аргументом re.VERBOSE, питон ругается, что я ему даю 3 элемента, вместо 2-х `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required`. Это из-за того, что как раз сам re.VERBOSE и является этим 3им элементом?

Comment: @vlad У меня не ругается, см. [пример](https://ideone.com/tAItF4).